# Restlet custom configuration properties files

Tags: configuration, restlet, properties-file

Frameworks like Spring, Struts facilitates for property file reading. For instance MessageResources in Struts. I want to know whether there are such property files which are in built supported by  Restlet framework itself. If there is one, then I will not need to re invent the wheel and be able to use it straight.My application configuration values will be included in that file. I am new to Restlet, I couldn't find any soulution. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no support like this in Restlet. That said you can leverage client protocols to load these properties files from difference locations:

- `Protocol.FILE` - from filesystem directly
- `Protocol.CLAP` - from classpath
- `Protocol.OBAP` - from OSGi bundle

Here is a sample:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("clap://someproperties.properties");
Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.load(cr.get().getStream());
```

You need to specify this protocol when defining your component:

```
Component component = new Component();
(...)
component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);
component.getClients().add(Protocol.CLAP);
```

Comment: Thanks Very much for your answer. I am new to restlets. What I understood from your answer is that properties are required to load from different location (another server calling server). If it is so, won't it be a performance drawback as the process will have to wait until the response is back.

Comment: No worries ;-) In fact protocols like `FILE` and `CLAP` are local and don't require a network call. It's something similar to use Reader or InputStream but through the Restlet API...

Comment: I tried as you mentioned. but it fails. May be I make something wrong. In one of my util class, I try to call exactly same as "ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("clap://someproperties.properties");
Properties props = new Properties(); 
props.load(cr.get().getStream());" . But there is an error "server not found anything matching the request URI" .  My property file is in the resource folder (it is a maven project). I am not clear how the 'Component' is used here and why it is neccessary as far as we call a file inside the project? any idea please?